# How to have different layouts for same size category devices?

Tags: android

I have 3 devices

**1)** galaxy nexus  **720*1280**  (`xhdpi`, normal size category )

**2)** motorola      **480*854**   (`hdpi`, normal size category)

**3)** htc           **320*480**   (`mdpi`, normal size category)

I have my xmls in my layout folder. In my xmls I need to fix sizes to my textviews,Edittext(it will expand with the text entering).

Because of this,I am getting problems in my motorolo,htc devices.I cannot able to prepare different layouts because these 3 devices are comes under layout-normal(layout).

I have Textviews in Rectangular background,with the text increases rect box is getting expanded.

Is there any option to prepare different layouts for each of the devices.

please suggest

Thanks

Comment: Resolution affects image resources not layout. Physical screen size affects layout.

Comment: I need to fix my textviews, Editext size because they will get expanded if we go on typing text.so I need to fix this values.How can I solve this?

Comment: Use `fill_parent`, `match_parent` as height/width. Or use `0dp` as height/width with `layout-weight` from `0.0` to `1.0`.

Comment: I have an EditText with background,if I give wrap_content and go on adding text this will expand,so I have fixed this width

Answer (score 1):

You can target densities by using a layout folder like `layout-mdpi`, `layout-hdpi` and a `layout-xhdpi`. Why would you want to do this? using dips for everything will be fine.

Edit: suggestions based on the comments you gave:

by using a value like 200dp, the boxes on all devices kinda have the same size. Not in pixels but in actual size on the screen. This is what dips (the dp unit) is made for.

The screens are supposed to look kinda the same on the different device sizes. Read the description on http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html especially the section named **"Density independence"**.

After reading that and if you still really, and I strongly suggest you don't do that, want them to look different on different screen sizes do this.

1. In your layout xml define the width as `android:layout_width="@dimen/the_width"`
2. In the folder values, create a file values.xml. In there define a dimension like this `<dimen name="the_width">200dp</dimen>`. 200dp is an example and will be the default value.
3. Override this value in the values-hdpi, values-xhdpi and/or values-mdpi folder, by creating the same values.xml, but with a different value for `the_width`.

This will make the edittext have a different size on different screen sizes.

Comment: no, I have background like rectangular box inside there will be a text  ,if I have a text of some 1 line with size fixed ,then when it comes to motorolo,htc, this background is getting expanded.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots to show what you mean? I'm having a hard time understanding this without seeing it. Can you also post the layout.xml you are using now?

Comment: sure ,give me some time, please try to understand by my words. I have an EditText with background,if I give wrap_content and go on adding text this will expand,so I have fixed this width

Comment: What happens if you just set the layout_width to something like 200dp? It should look the same on all devices. You can also define this variable in as a dimen resource in a values.xml `<dimen name="your_name">200dp</dimen>`. And only change that for each of the devices. Then you don't need separate layouts and it becomes easier to manage.

Comment: ya if I set 200dp as width,it is looking big in my hdpi,mdpi devices which I mentioned above. so how can I set this width for all these three devices